Getting "ILLEGAL_SASL_STATE: Request is not valid given the current SASL state" in redpanda after setting up authentication+authorization
We're trying to set up redpanda authorization but getting a strange "ILLEGAL_SASL_STATE: Request is not valid given the current SASL state" after following the instructions in the documentation.
We're using self-hosted quickstart with docker-compose here https://docs.redpanda.com/current/get-started/quick-start/
And using the authentication and authorization instructions here https://docs.redpanda.com/current/manage/security/authentication/
Just using the exact instructions... and setting up authentication and authorization runs fine without error... It's just when we try to perform docker exec -it redpanda-0 rpk topic create chat-room -X user=u1 -X pass=p1 -X sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256, it throws that error.
Tried
docker exec -it redpanda-0 rpk topic create chat-room -X user=u1 -X pass=p1 -X sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
and it throws that error.
Tried disabling authentication and authorization, and it goes back to working fine.
